# Core Data adding new ViewController (Lynda tutorial)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have followed a tutorial on Lynda.com for `CoreData`, and it all works well but when I try to add a new `UIViewController` (which will be the initial `UIViewController`) instead of the `UITableViewController` it crashes.  I thought maybe changing the `objectIndex` in my app delegate to 1 would work, so now it is the 2nd object in the navigation controller.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    PersonTableTableViewController *ptvc = (PersonTableTableViewController *)[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];
    ptvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas would be great, I know this is simple fix but I've been struggling with it

Comment: Can you explain your current, and desired, view controller hierarchy a little more?  May be post a snapshot of your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the initial view controller just import that view controller and create the instance of the view controller and replace it with the PersonTableTableViewController instance. Lets say you want to have PersonListTableViewController as initial view controller then you can initialise like this, go to the storyboard and replace the navigationcontroller's rootviewcontroller to PersonListViewController and use the below code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    PersonListTableViewController *ptvc = (PersonListTableViewController *)[[nav viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
    ptvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this is the same as i already have,  i did try adding a new ViewController which i called HomeViewController and i wanted that as initial ViewController, and i replaced everything in the above code with HomeViewController but it didn't recognise the 'managedObjectcontext'

Comment: you need to create the instance of managedObjectcontext in HomeViewController.h